# How to add odd and even class in group?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add odd and even class in pairing. So how can i do it with php.

```
<div class="root">
    <div class="odd">
    </div>
    <div class="odd">
    </div>    
    <div class="even">
    </div>
    <div class="even">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create structure in wordpress post loop.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
   'cat' => 1
 );
 $html = '';
 // The Query
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts()){
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

  }
}
```

So how can i do it. Please suggest me some ideas.

Comment: use the modulus operator (%)... use a counter on the posts and if the counter%2 is 0, then the post is even, and if it is 1, then the post is an odd number. t/hen you can implement logic to group them accordingly.

Comment: Actually my question is wrong now i had updated my question please see update

Answer (score 1):

Use counter to check how many row you have printed and reset it when you want to start over:

```
<?php
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        $count = 0;
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            if($count < 2){
                // add <div class="odd"> block here
            }else{
                // add <div class="even"> block here            
            }
            $count++;
            if($count == 4){
                $count = 0;
            }            
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
$class = 'even';
echo '<div class="root">';
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $class = $class != 'even' ? 'even' : 'odd';
    echo "<div class='{$class}'></div>";
    echo "<div class='{$class}'></div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Not working... 
actually i want  structure like FASHION LIVE section of 
http://www.premierevision.com/

Comment: Ya thats right but if i use that i will get inner html two times. its wordpress post loop and we print title and content of each post in odd and even div so in while loop i can write following code single time